# NodeJS How to handle multiple TCP connection using socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am trying to build a socket server using Node.js. The server need to handle multiple TCP connections. Here is my code:

```
const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = 5000;

var app = require('net')();
var sleep = require('sleep');

var server = net.createServer().listen(PORT, HOST);
server.on('connection', function(sock){
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
    var c = 0;
    while(true){
        sock.write(c.toString()+' ');
        c++;
        sleep.sleep(1);
    }
});
console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
```

How to handle all connections parallelly instead of queueing? Thanks :D

Comment: `How to handle all connections parallelly instead of queueing?` you are 'queuing' because you blocked the event loop with this `while(true)`. this said, node is single thread, everything is sequential, but fast enough to give the feel it is //, for true //ism, use another language like `go`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, you are blocking the event loop with `while(true)`, instead try using `setInterval` instead, to achieve the desired result:

```
setInterval(function() {
    sock.write(c.toString()+' ');
    c++;
}, 1000)
```

Comment: This answer is what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question.

But every client will trigger the server.on('connection'), request which will be available through your sock variable for as long as the user is still there. Instead of trying to block your server to remind of the user, you need to think of an event based configuration, which will have two kind of events sock.on which will get an event fired from the client and an emit event which will send data to the targeted client.

so you could imagine something like this

```
server.on('connection', function(sock){
    sock.on('event_name', function(data_received){ 
       // Some stuff
    });
    sock.emit("connected", {"message", "Hi From the server"});
});
```

I think [socket.io is a great place to start](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Thank you. I used to handle connections by creating a new thread when I write it in Java. Java is not an event driven language.

Comment: In case it might get helpfull there is a java client for socket io : https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java